# Move item with arrow keys and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an item that can be dragged within a shape. I had been also able to move the item with the arrow keys on the keyboard, using:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 63232){ // up arrow key
    if(!event.shiftKey) howMuch = -1;   
    else if(event.shiftKey) howMuch = -10;   
    moveText(howMuch);   
  }
});
```

But, at least in FF, this doesn't work anymore. I alerted out the event that is happening on an arrow press and all four return zero.

How can I detect an arrow key press? Oh yeah...javascript or jQuery.

Thank you for your time,
Todd

Comment: What about using `keydown` instead?

Comment: What is 63232? Seems a bit high.

Comment: Yes it is high...on on older Mac maybe that is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) { // Note I used .on()
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {                // I never use .which
        howMuch = (e.shiftKey) ? -10 : -1;
    }
    moveText(howMuch); // never seen this function before, isn't that it?
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting a value of 0 for event.which but event.keyCode seems to work. Any ideas as to why event.which is not working like everyone else thinks it should?

Comment: No idea. I have absolutely _no_ reason to prefer `keyCode`, I only know it works, and I've never used `which`. But it might be a jQuery bug, did you update your version lately? @maddogandnoriko

Answer (score 3):

The keycode you're using is wrong, the up arrow is 38:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 38) {
        moveText(event.shiftKey ? -10 : -1);   
    }
});
```

Arrow keycodes for reference:

- Left: 37
- Up: 38
- Right: 39
- Down: 40

To find other keycodes check the example for [keyPress() in the API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: For some reason event.which is returning 0 not 37,38,39, or 40, in Firefox in Coda it is 63232, etc.